# Sampling on a spline to a given max chordal deviation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm looking for a fast way to sample points on a spline such that a polygon or linestring through those points does not exceed a given chordal error to the original spline. I have an algorithm I wrote some time ago that produces the results in the picture (see code below if interested; I'm not expecting anyone to pore over it). It works OK, but fast it is not (~2 seconds on my computer to generate that graphic). Is there something easier, maybe built into numpy or scipy that will accomplish this?

Thanks

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from scipy.interpolate import splev

def get_rhos(ts, tck):
    """Get (signed) rhos (1/rad of curvature) for a given
    set of t values.
    """
    tanvs = np.array(splev(ts, tck, der=1)).T
    accvs = np.array(splev(ts, tck, der=2)).T
    if tanvs.ndim == 1:
        tanvs = tanvs.reshape(1, -1)
        accvs = accvs.reshape(1, -1)

    crossp = np.cross(accvs, tanvs, axis=1)
    tanvms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.dot(v, v)) for v in tanvs])
    rhos = crossp / tanvms**3
    return rhos

def calc_rad(pt0, pt1, pt2, calcdrop=False):
    """Calculate a radius from three points on the arc.
    Lifted from http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=173847
    """
    pt0 = np.array(pt0)
    pt1 = np.array(pt1)
    pt2 = np.array(pt2)

    v0 = pt1 - pt0
    v1 = pt2 - pt0
    v2 = pt2 - pt1
    a = np.sqrt(np.dot(v0, v0))
    b = np.sqrt(np.dot(v1, v1))
    c = np.sqrt(np.dot(v2, v2))
    R = (a*b*c) / np.sqrt(  2 * a**2 * b**2
                          + 2 * b**2 * c**2
                          + 2 * c**2 * a**2
                          - a**4 - b**4 - c**4)
    if calcdrop:
        # Calculate arc drop
        drop = R - np.sqrt(R**2 - (b/2.)**2)
        return R, drop
    else:
        return R

def chordal_sample(tck, chordaltol, oversample=10):
    """Given a spline definition and a chordal tolerance
    (intol/outol), get the t-values for the spline such
    that, when adjacent points are connected, the chordal
    tolerance is not violated.

    Accomplishes this by bracketing a solution, then using
    the brentq solver to find the point where the chordal
    error equals the chordal tolerance.

    Note that a few extra points may be inserted where there
    are inflections in the cubic; these are sometimes missed
    by the arc-radius-calculating portion of the code.
    """

    # This is the function we'll need when we have to
    # go searching for the answer via brentq
    def makeerrfunc(st, spt, tck, chordaltol):
        def errfunc(et):
            mt = (st + et) / 2.0
            mpt = np.array(splev(mt, tck))
            ept = np.array(splev(et, tck))
            _, arcdrop = calc_rad(spt, mpt, ept, calcdrop=True)
            diff = arcdrop - chordaltol
            return diff
        return errfunc

    # Make sure we're sampling enough points
    # TODO: How can we be sure?
    ts = np.linspace(0, 1, oversample * len(tck[1][0]))
    newts = [0]
    # Loop through the time values
    for nt in ts:
        st = newts[-1]
        rts = ts[ts > st] # Only consider remaining time values
        # Step through adjacent pairs of time values and find
        # ones that bracket the solution.
        for et0, et1 in zip(rts[0:-1], rts[1:]):
            # Get a 'middle time' that we can use to calc
            # a 'middle point' for our arc calculations
            mt0 = (st + et0) / 2.
            mt1 = (st + et1) / 2.

            # Interpolate points at the critical t values
            ipts = np.array(splev([st, mt0, et0, mt1, et1], tck))
            spt, mpt0, ept0, mpt1, ept1 = ipts.T

            _, arcdrop0 = calc_rad(spt, mpt0, ept0, calcdrop=True)
            _, arcdrop1 = calc_rad(spt, mpt1, ept1, calcdrop=True)

            # Have we bracketed the solution yet? If so, use
            # brentq to find a better one within the bracketed
            # range, then move on to a new start t.
            if arcdrop0 > chordaltol: # Check the initial pair
                errfunc = makeerrfunc(st, spt, tck, chordaltol)
                mdt = brentq(errfunc, st, et0)
                newts.append(mdt)
                break
            if arcdrop0 <= chordaltol and arcdrop1 > chordaltol:
                errfunc = makeerrfunc(st, spt, tck, chordaltol)
                mdt = brentq(errfunc, et0, et1)
                newts.append(mdt)
                break
            # Check for the existence of an inflection point
            # in the bracketed range by checking the signs
            # of the two calculated curvatures and looking for
            # a reversal.
            if get_rhos(et0, tck)[0] * get_rhos(et1, tck)[0] < 0:
                newts.append((et0 + et1) / 2.0)
                break
        if et1 == 1.0: # No more points to try
            newts.append(1.0)
            break
    return newts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.interpolate import splprep

    # Create a hi-res sample spline. Start with some
    # low-res points and then resample at a higher
    # res.
    XY = np.array([[0.0,  1.0,  2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                   [0.0, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 2.5, 1.2, 2.0]])
    tck, u = splprep(XY, s=0)
    XY = splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 400), tck)
    tck, u = splprep(XY, s=0)

    # Get a set of t values that will plot out
    # a linestring with no more than 0.1 chordal
    # error to the original.
    ts = chordal_sample(tck, 0.1)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # Plot the hi-res spline
    ax.plot(*XY)
    # Plot the approximated spline
    ax.plot(*np.array(splev(ts, tck)), marker='o')

    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great solution in one of my favorite modules - Shapely. There's a `simplify()` method on Shapely geometric objects that takes a tolerance and produces this for the same 0.1 value:
[image]

Looks better to me, and only took 1.65 ms (for a ~1200x speedup)!